# Twitter bootstrap - Glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using amazon s3.

My glyphicons don't show up.

I added the following to my head

```
<style>
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>
```

I thought it would overwrite the old path, but I still can not see the glyphicons.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have access to that image publicly?  I get this error when pulling up the image: XPath/RenderXSL
<Error>
<Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code>
<Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>
<RequestId>C67E5A43B8890C6D</RequestId>
<HostId>jBackG5hjmjnfT+NwR6YUsA/bXZDXBzqzsouItyZW1rYiHiylPU/pKFIaE71eFgb</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Yes I have access, the link above was just an example. https://s3.amazonaws.com/elobeast-assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png

Comment: Is your style element defined *after* you reference the bootstrap css files?

Comment: yes it is the last thing in the head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue - and have narrowed it down to the `.css` using the production CDN instead of TEST.

On heroku I have `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV` set to test however it still compiles the CSS with the Production CDN.

Other assets show the correct CDN, Prod CDN seems to be used due to folowing:

```
@iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png');
```

Answer (score 6):

Each sprite has a `background-position` where it's located and you are overwriting them all with that styles. As you only want to change the source of your sprites, use:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
    background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
}
```